# jquery check radio button not displayed

Tags: jquery

I need to check a radio button trough jquery. There for I use the following line of code:

```
$(this).prop("checked",true);
```

Using Jquery > 1.10 this should work. If I check the status of the radio button before and after changing it, it seems to work.

```
window.alert($(this).prop("checked") //results in false
$(this).prop("checked",true);
window.alert($(this).prop("checked") //results in true
```

So the button is checked, but it's not visible in the browser. Not in Chrome nor in IE. What am I missing here? I don't use Jquery UI so, as far I known I don't need to refresh the buttonset.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: How checked and visible is related?

Comment: hmm, checked the code in jsfiddle, and it's working. So must do something wrong. window.alert($(this).is(":checked") returns false..

Answer (score 0):

You're only change the checked state, you need to show it as well using **[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** if it's hidden:

```
$(this).prop("checked",true).show();
```

Comment: the element is not hidden. So show() doesn't help. I tried a lot of options, but still no luck. I can set the status to checked, but when I submit the form, the value from the radio button is not passed. The weird thing is that simple test setups do work. Only this is a complex form, but I can't find whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the problem sits somewhere else. If I address the radio button directly I can change it, so I must be doing somewhere, something that messes this up.

The function it self works and is nothing wrong with.

Found the problem.. I need more coffee.